# Convert from decimal to hexadecimal in cmake

Tags: cmake

The Y:
Is it possible to take a variable A with 16 decimal and convert it to 10 hexadecimal, and vice versa, in a CMake?

Google searching only led me to the following:

http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2008-September/024092.html

Which doesn't do the conversion.

The X:
I'm trying to use "Configure File", reading the configured value as a decimal and outputting it as a hexadecimal in the configured header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rolled my own, but this feels like it should be  a built-in

```
    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6.4)

    macro(HEXCHAR2DEC VAR VAL)
        if (${VAL} MATCHES "[0-9]")
            SET(${VAR} ${VAL})
        elseif(${VAL} MATCHES "[aA]")
            SET(${VAR} 10)
        elseif(${VAL} MATCHES "[bB]")
            SET(${VAR} 11)
        elseif(${VAL} MATCHES "[cC]")
            SET(${VAR} 12)
        elseif(${VAL} MATCHES "[dD]")
            SET(${VAR} 13)
        elseif(${VAL} MATCHES "[eE]")
            SET(${VAR} 14)
        elseif(${VAL} MATCHES "[fF]")
            SET(${VAR} 15)
        else()
            MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid format for hexidecimal character")
        endif()

    endmacro(HEXCHAR2DEC)

    macro(HEX2DEC VAR VAL)

        IF (${VAL} EQUAL 0)
            SET(${VAR} 0)
        ELSE()

            SET(CURINDEX 0)
            STRING(LENGTH "${VAL}" CURLENGTH)

            SET(${VAR} 0)

            while (CURINDEX LESS  CURLENGTH)

                STRING(SUBSTRING "${VAL}" ${CURINDEX} 1 CHAR)

                HEXCHAR2DEC(CHAR ${CHAR})

                MATH(EXPR POWAH "(1<<((${CURLENGTH}-${CURINDEX}-1)*4))")
                MATH(EXPR CHAR "(${CHAR}*${POWAH})")
                MATH(EXPR ${VAR} "${${VAR}}+${CHAR}")
                MATH(EXPR CURINDEX "${CURINDEX}+1")
            endwhile()
        ENDIF()

    endmacro(HEX2DEC)

    macro(DECCHAR2HEX VAR VAL)

        if (${VAL} LESS 10)
            SET(${VAR} ${VAL})
        elseif(${VAL} EQUAL 10)
            SET(${VAR} "A")
        elseif(${VAL} EQUAL 11)
            SET(${VAR} "B")
        elseif(${VAL} EQUAL 12)
            SET(${VAR} "C")
        elseif(${VAL} EQUAL 13)
            SET(${VAR} "D")
        elseif(${VAL} EQUAL 14)
            SET(${VAR} "E")
        elseif(${VAL} EQUAL 15)
            SET(${VAR} "F")
        else()
            MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid format for hexidecimal character")
        endif()
    endmacro(DECCHAR2HEX)

    macro(DEC2HEX VAR VAL)
        if (${VAL} EQUAL 0)
            SET(${VAR} 0)
        ELSE()
            SET(VAL2 ${VAL})
            SET(${VAR} "")

            WHILE (${VAL2} GREATER 0)
                MATH(EXPR VALCHAR "(${VAL2}&15)")
                DECCHAR2HEX(VALCHAR ${VALCHAR})
                SET(${VAR} "${VALCHAR}${${VAR}}")
                MATH(EXPR VAL2 "${VAL2} >> 4")
            ENDWHILE()
        ENDIF()
    endmacro(DEC2HEX)
```

Comment: Would be nice to provide an example of usage for those functions

Answer (score 1):

Using some tricks you can do this fairly simply. CMake's expressions use `int` internally, so it only works up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 bits. Something like this (you might want to alter it for big endian or whatever).

```
function (NumberToHex number output)
    set (chars "0123456789abcdef")
    set (hex "")

    foreach (i RANGE 7)
        math (EXPR nibble "${number} & 15")
        string (SUBSTRING "${chars}" "${nibble}" 1 nibble_hex)
        string (APPEND hex "${nibble_hex}")

        math (EXPR number "${number} >> 4")
    endforeach ()

    string (REGEX REPLACE "(.)(.)" "\\2\\1" hex "${hex}")
    set ("${output}" "${hex}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction ()
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! However I believe that the REGEX REPLACE at the end is wrong, because it inverts adjacent characters instead of reversing the whole string. I solved it by transforming the string to a list with REGEX MATCHALL "(.)", then reversing the list, then building a new string.

Comment: You might also want to avoid leading zeroes by adding an if(${number} EQUAL 0) break() endif() to the end of the loop

Comment: @SamuelPeter: Depends on what you want exactly I guess. This was for the byte-wise hex representation of a little endian int, e.g. 258 -> 0201. If you just want a 'normal' hex number (not sure why you would) it is easier to just prepend the hex digits in the loop, then you don't even need the regex. E.g. `set(hex "${nibble_hex}${hex}")`.

Comment: Oh yes that's better, thanks! Yeah I needed to manipulate normal hex numbers that we use in version numbers. You don't #define constants using little endian bytes ;)

Comment: You don't normally use hex in version numbers either tbf!